# Get and unpack latest version of dependency without a pom file

Tags: maven, resources, dependencies

Is this possible? I need to be able to use Maven to download a dependency to a specific directory and unpack it there, not knowing the version number. I can get close, with maven-dependency-plugin:2.7:get providing the "dest" param and using "LATEST" in the artifact param. It gets the resource (a tarball) downloaded to where I want it. But now I'd like maven to also extract it.

So since versions newer than 2.7 recommend using maven-dependency-plugin:copy if I need the dest param, I thought I could use maven-dependency-plugin:unpack (the same as copy, but unpacks the dependency in the process). However, both copy and unpack require the artifact have a version number, so I'm stuck.

Also tried using maven-dependency-plugin:get with no dest, then maven-dependency-plugin:unpack-dependencies in the same command, but seems unpack-dependencies requires a pom file to work. Bummer.

Is there a way to get the version number of the latest and somehow make it used in the unpack command, without any sort of bash trickery (stuck using just mvn commands)?

Comment: Have you checked if you can use a version range in the artifactItem of maven-dependency-plugin apart from that you should use an up-to-date [version 2.9](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/).

Answer (score 0):

For unpacking, try this:

```
    <plugin>
         <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>1.7</version>
          <executions>
                <execution>
                   <phase>package</phase>
                   <id>Unpack</id>
                   <configuration>
                   <target>
                        <untar src="some_dependency_*.tar" dest="${proj.home}"/>
                   </target>
            </execution>
           </executions>
    </plugin>
```